# plotting sine wave on display with Stop/Pause/Play buttons by using C

Tags: c, macos, signal-processing

I'm trying to create one thread to produce sample of sine wave and create another thread
to read the sample from the buffer and plot on the screen and update the display with certain interval by using GUI.

My questions are

1. Is there any library for implementing oscilloscope-like display with the Stop/Pause/Play buttons in C??
2. if not, is it possible to transfer the sample of sine wave generated from C code to the other program(designed by different language that support better GUI library)?

Comment: What OS/platform/GUI are you using ???

Comment: I'm using Mac/I didn't decide platform and GUI to use.

Comment: OK - I've added an appropriate tag for you now.

Comment: Thanks Paul. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to go. If you spend some time googling around you will find C libraries to do plotting (like [koolplot](http://koolplot.codecutter.org/)). If you can consider C++ and wonderful Qt project to implement whatever you're developing, you may take a look at [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) library. Qt+qwt work fine on Mac OS.